# How could I enable bootchart for Android L MR1 5.1

Tags: android, performance

I am investigating android first time boot up, and want to enable bootchart, but I always get failed, below is what I have done, someone could help me?

because the bootchart service start up earlier than  /data partition mount, so every time bootchart failed to init.
the failure message from kernel log is : bootcharting init failure

so in order to ensure bootchart init sucessfully,  I have changed related code. and this solution can work well in Android L, but failed in Android L MR1.
phone keep restart after implement below change; after I disable selinux, phone block at first logo.

---

```
init/bootchart.c
/* called to setup bootcharting */
int   bootchart_init( void )
{
    int  ret;
    char buff[4];
    int  timeout = 0, count = 0;

    buff[0] = 0;

+    /* wait until /data mounted */
+    struct stat datadir;
+    if(stat("/data/bootchart-start", &datadir) == -1) {
+    ERROR("Bootchart, /data/bootchart-start not exists\n");
+    return -1;
+    }
    proc_read( LOG_STARTFILE, buff, sizeof(buff) );
    if (buff[0] != 0) {
        timeout = atoi(buff);
    }
```

---

```
init/init.c
static int bootchart_init_action(int nargs, char **args)
{
    bootchart_count = bootchart_init();
    if (bootchart_count < 0) {
        ERROR("bootcharting init failure\n");
+   queue_builtin_action(bootchart_init_action, "bootchart_init");
    } else if (bootchart_count > 0) {
        NOTICE("bootcharting started (period=%d ms)\n", bootchart_count*BOOTCHART_POLLING_MS);
    } else {
        NOTICE("bootcharting ignored\n");
    }
```

---

```
rootdir/init.rc
on post-fs-data
    # We chown/chmod /data again so because mount is run as root + defaults
    chown system system /data
    chmod 0771 /data
    # We restorecon /data in case the userdata partition has been reset.
    restorecon /data

+    write /data/bootchart-start 600
    # Avoid predictable entropy pool. Carry over entropy from previous boot.
    copy /data/system/entropy.dat /dev/urandom
```

---

```
/system/core/init/Android.mk

+ INIT_BOOTCHART :=true
ifeq ($(strip $(INIT_BOOTCHART)),true)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += bootchart.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DBOOTCHART=1
endif
```

---

Is there someone ever enable bootchart on android L MR1 ? How could you change code for?
How could I modify code to ensure bootchart init running after /data/ partition mounted?

Thank you in advance! It is very serious to me.

Comment: Is there somebody can answer my question? Don't you ever try to enable bootchart on Android 5.1 ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable bootchart for first boot by this `init.rc`:

```
on post-fs-data
    # We chown/chmod /data again so because mount is run as root + defaults
    chown system system /data
    chmod 0771 /data
    # We restorecon /data in case the userdata partition has been reset.
    restorecon /data

    # start debuggerd to make debugging early-boot crashes easier.
    start debuggerd
    start debuggerd64

    # Make sure we have the device encryption key.
    start vold
    installkey /data

    # Start bootcharting as soon as possible after the data partition is
    # mounted to collect more data.
    mkdir /data/bootchart 0755 shell shell
    # if you need to enable bootchart uncomment next line
    # Old Android
    # write /data/bootchart-start 120 
    # Android > 7.0
    # write /data/bootchart/start 120 
    bootchart_init
```